# How can I show "Invalid login attempt" message inside bootstrap modal popup's login partial view without redirection to a new login page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a bootstrap modal popup which has two partial views login and registration [image: as shown here]

When I enter a wrong passsword, it should show me "Invalid login attempt" inside the popup login partial view but it redirects me to a different new login partial view page ([image: Invalid login attempt in a completely new page]

How can I rectify this? I want the message "Invalid login attempt" to be shown in login popup without any redirection to another page?

[image: Here's my project structure]

Login code

```
             // POST: /Account/Login
                [HttpPost]
                [AllowAnonymous]
                [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
                //[ChildActionOnly]
                public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
                {
      
                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", 
                            new { area = "Landing" });

                        //return View(model);
                    }

                    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
                    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email,
                        model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
                    switch (result)
                    {
                        case SignInStatus.Success:
                            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                            return View("Lockout");
                        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                        case SignInStatus.Failure:
                        default:
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                            return PartialView("_Login",model);

                    }
                }
```

Comment: It doesn't matter if its return View(model) or return PartialView(model), it gives same result - redirect to a new page _Login.cshtml Page

Comment: Wel, if you using code behind and a post back, then i can't see how a pop dialog based on jQuery.UI or even a boottrap dialog going to survice a post back? The instant you do a  post back ,the page travels up to server, code behind runs, and then you get a fresh new web page - and you dialog is LONG gone. You have to adopt a ajax web service call and dump post-backs. Or just use a whole page - and not use a popup dialog - your choice.

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is not correct:

```
default:
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
    return PartialView("_Login",model);
```

You cannot return a `PartialView` as `ActinoResult` you would have to return a `View`

---

You need to return the same `View` as your Login page, but add the Model error and the Login page would display Model error, so first, here:

```
// if ModelStat is not valid, then the Model already has the Validation error
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return View(model); // <-- returns the same View (Login View)
}
```

And here you need something like this:

```
default:
    // login has failed, add the Model error and return to the same Login View
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
    return View(model);
```